# Tableau Dimension grouping and Using two date fields?

Tags: tableau-api, calculation

I have two questions. First - I am trying to create a new status using Jobstatus as shown below. How do I combine "Installation_Complete" & "Unviable" into a new field name "Total Visited", How do I combine "Installation_Complete" & "Unviable" & "Need_Reschedule" into a new field name "Total Scheduled"? As well as have "Installation_Complete" as Total Installed? Example below ideally it would look like this for WK45...

Total Scheduled - 1,985

Total Visited - 1,925

Total Installed - 1,859
[image]

2nd Question - In my workbook I am primarily using two Date fields. "install_date" & "date". Installation_Complete should be referencing "install_date" while Need_reschedule & Unviable should be referencing "date". In the picture above I am using "date" in columns, so the Installation_complete is actually skewed because of the date field I am using, so how would I use both date fields?

Ex. WK45 - Installation_Complete should be referencing 'Install_date" WK45 while Need_Reschedule & Unviable should be referencing "date" WK45

It would be very helpful if anyone could help me out with their input!

Thanks,

Phillip

Comment: Can you please attach some sample/fake data, as per format of your data, so that it can be copied and tried?

Comment: Doesn't the answer served the desired purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not given any data that can be copied, I tried recreating some sample data

[image]

This was arranged in a crosstab view like you uploaded as a screenshot

[image]

Perhaps you want this.

[image]

To this I have added a table calculation `Running sum` on `table down` and edited the aliases.  For more clarification, please upload some sample data that can be copied (not as screenshot).  Good Luck

**PS** In you screenshot the grand totals are arithmetically incorrect.  Please have a look.